# Boton de retorno a formulario con sus valores laravel

Tags: laravel, formularios

No he encontrado nada en interenet o si pero no lo se aplicar
Tengo un formulario el cual tiene muchos campos "select". El formulario se envia, y la pagina de resultado tiene un boton de volver a la la pagina del form. Bueno, el tema es que me gustaria que una vez pulse el boton de volver atras, los campos del formulario estuvieran con los valores con los cuales se envió. 
He probado de todo, pero, o no se utilizarlo, o no se. Esto del Old input, nunca lo habia utlizado hasta ahora.

Gracias de Antemano!!

Comment: quizá en el `onclick` manejando el `history` de `window.` , ejm : `<button onclick="return window.history.back();">Retroceder</button>`

Comment: El formulario se envía mediante `POST` o `GET`? Para evitar este tipo de consultas, siempre es importante que publiques tu código.

Answer (score 2):

Esto lo puedes poner en la parte de tu controlador donde indicas que la información se envío correctamente;

```
return redirect()->back() //regresamos al mismo sitio del formulario
                 ->withInput($request->all()); //acá retornas toda la info enviada
```

No es necesario que agreges javascript ni ninguna otra cosa exterior.

Documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#retrieving-input (aplica para versiones >=5)

Intenta hacer tus búsquedas en inglés para que obtengas más y mejores  ejemplos.